# ODBC source in Loop in SSIS package built to MS SQL is failing in 2nd round

Tags: sql-server, ssis, odbc, firebird

I am PowerBI freelancer and I use SSIS packages to load data from original sources to MS SQL DWH. One of sources is book keeping app named MRP, which use FireBird db. There are many companies booked in App MRP and data of each company are stored in standalone db file and MS SQL DWH and Firebird db files are on the same PC. I created SSIS packages in Visual studio and scheme of flow is in attached pictures.

[image: see package]

[image: see ODBC Source detail]

I use ODBC connector, where the connection string is created in each loop for each company in list.

[image: see connection string definition]

Everything is working ok in Visual studio and package is loading all companies one by one to DWH. I built this solution to Integration services Catalog and run jobs to call each package. Trouble is that each run of package is failing in 2nd run of loop it means first firebird file is loaded ok but any second file not. Here are screens from SQL jobs runs
[image: job fail]

[image: SSIS messages details]

The same schema is used in another client with firebird files and is running OK but here not I am not able to investigate why? Any advice or the same experience? I would appreciate your help.

I investigate around the world but I haven't found similar issue with ODBC connectors used in loop in SSIS package. I tried delay rounds. I tried to ask ChatGPT but only general advice to ask somewhere

Comment: You can try to set **RetainSameConnection** property to False or True: https://mitchellpearson.com/2015/01/12/ssis-performance-tuning-the-for-each-loop-retain-same-connection/#:~:text=Retain%20Same%20Connection%20is%20a,is%20opened%20and%20subsequently%20closed.

Comment: Also consider using a Firebird URL that doesn't consist solely of the database filename, but instead includes the host name and port (e.g. `dbname=localhost/3050:C:/MRP1/DATA0544.mrp`), assuming of course you actually have a Firebird server running, and aren't using Firebird in embedded mode.

Comment: Hi guys, thanks for your attention and the hope which you provided to me. I tried change RetainSameConnection and change path to file as suggested, but with the same result and the same fail in 2nd round of loop :(

Comment: It looks like you forgot to close result sets used by LoadToLanding and try to reopen what is already open at the second iteration.

Comment: And may I ask you how to close resultset? As I wrote the same algoritmus is working in another project with similar firebird db's

Comment: Hi everybody, I found solution - I changed ODBC Source to ADO.NET source and built solution has started working, but I am still interested in finding answer why ODBC source didnt work.